# Recover connection when a new master is elected in the cluster

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I've a Redis cluster with 3 nodes; 1 is the master and the other 2 are slaves, holding the replica of the master. When I kill the master instance, Redis Sentinel promotes another node to be the master, which starts to accept writes.

During my tests I noticed that once the new master is promoted, the first operation in Redis with SE.Redis fails with:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on GET
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host

To avoid it, I've implemented a retry logic as below. Is there any better alternative?

```
private RedisValue RedisGet(string key)
{
    return RedisOperation(() =>
    {
        RedisKey redisKey = key;
        RedisValue redisValue = connection.StringGet(redisKey);
        return (redisValue);
    });
}

private T RedisOperation<T>(Func<T> act)
{
    int timeToSleepBeforeRetryInMiliseconds = 20;
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            return act();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to perform REDIS OP");

            TimeSpan passedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            if (this.retryTimeout < passedTime)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ABORTING re-try to REDIS OP");
                throw;
            }
            else
            {
                int remainingTimeout = (int)(this.retryTimeout.TotalMilliseconds - passedTime.TotalMilliseconds);
                // if remaining time is less than 1 sec than wait only for that much time and than give a last try
                if (remainingTimeout < timeToSleepBeforeRetryInMiliseconds)
                {
                    timeToSleepBeforeRetryInMiliseconds = remainingTimeout;
                }
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Sleeping " + timeToSleepBeforeRetryInMiliseconds + " before next try");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeToSleepBeforeRetryInMiliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: don't use Sentinel with Stackexchange.Redis as Sentinel support is still not implemented in this client library.

See https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/labels/sentinel for all the open issues, there is also a pretty good PR open for ~1 year now.

That being said, I also had relatively good experience with retries, but I would never use that approach in production as it is not reliable at all.